# Xdebug in remote PhpStorm doesn't work with project in Virtual Box by SSH

Tags: ssh, phpstorm, virtualbox, xdebug

Host is Windows. In virtual machine - Ubuntu, and there is a PHP-project in Docker container, adapter is Bridge, access from host through IP 192.168.0.104. In virtual machine project maps upon IP 172.16.100.1 (port 10443). I have opened this project with JetBrains Gateway in host system, having installed PhpStorm into VM. Settings in PhpStorm:

[image: Settings PHP]

[image: Settings PHP > Debug]

[image: Settings PHP > Debug > DBGp Proxy]

[image: Settings PHP > Servers]

File xdebug.ini:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.mode=coverage,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=172.16.100.1
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
; xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
; xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Same file later:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=coverage,debug
xdebug.client_host=172.16.100.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
```

By the result of 9003 port analysis I guess, that this port is been listened (called in VM):

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 9003
ld-linux- 12243           pavel  296u  IPv6 262575      0t0  TCP *:9003 (LISTEN)
```

I have turned Xdebug on and set a breakpoint in the beginning of index.php. Making ssh-tunnel in PowerShell:

```
ssh -R 9000:localhost:9003 pavel@md.mydomain.local
```

`md.mydomain.local` linked in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` to IP `192.168.0.104`.

Navigating in browser `md.mydomain.local:10443` - remote PhpStorm neither stop, nor produce message like "... without being paused"

Comment: To be honest I didn’t completely understand your setup, but what I have just recently found out - and this might play a role in your setup - is that if you have a host-only network for you VirtualBox VM your host will be able to connect to VM but NOT the other way around.

Comment: Cannot comment on your problem due to a specific set up (Virtual Box with Docker and JetBrains Gateway) .. but a few general notes: 1) Do you actually use DBGp Proxy? Do you know what is it for? Do you know that you actually need to have the actual Proxy software installed and running? You do not need for local/container dev.

Comment: 2) Your Xdebug settings -- you have both Xdebug v2 and v3 params mixed together with different values (i.e. port 9000 for v2 and 9003 for v3). Stick to the version that you actually have -- help with misunderstandings (as it looks like you may be using them in a wrong way (they look messed up)). Most of params for v2 do nothing in v3. Also check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: Other than that: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html 3) https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/08/quickstart-with-docker-in-phpstorm/

Comment: @zobo, changed to a host-only network, but it didn't help

Comment: @LazyOne my XDebud version is 3.1.6. I have rewriten my xdebug.ini, having placed there only 4 params like here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html#prepare-the-debugging-engine, but it anywhere doesn't work. At first, how can I check, that navigating to `md.mydomain.local:10443` more or less reflects OS in VM? Maybe the command like `ssh -R 9003:localhost:9003 username@hostname` works in Windows in another way?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html -- "Remote debugging via SSH tunnel". SSH works the same. But VirtualBox may have certain "nuances" (as per comment by zobo). I have not used VirtualBox for ages (maybe over 10 years by now), and even when used it that was not for PHP development. I really cannot give any good advices here for such a set up / VM used (especially Gateway -- never used it myself so no comments on it). P.S. I suggest you update the question with the latest php.ini that you're using(to avoid any possible misunderstandings on that area)

Comment: With this setup, you don't need an SSH tunnel. We can also ignore the fact that it's all running in Windows because PhpStorm runs in the VM through Remote Development; so, from the Xdebug point of view, we have a Linux machine that runs a Docker container where you have a web server.
Now, you need to find which hostname the container can use to connect to the VM (and not to the Windows host as you seem to have wanted), and use this hostname as `xdebug.client_host`. Usually, `host.docker.internal` works okay

Comment: Also, make sure to disable `Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations` until you actually get a debug session in PhpStorm - it's 100% that the PHP | Servers entry that you manually created is wrong, and thus all incoming sessions will be ignored

Comment: @EugeneMorozov right you are, it works. Could you print at as an answer, for I could mark it as a solution?

Comment: @Rob, but I'haven't posted any images of code or other text examples. Only screenshots of IDE settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this setup, you don't need an SSH tunnel.

We can also ignore the fact that it's all running in Windows because PhpStorm runs in the VM through Remote Development; so, from the Xdebug point of view, we have a Linux machine that runs a Docker container where you have a web server.

Now, you need to find which hostname the container can use to connect to the VM (and not to the Windows host as you seem to have wanted), and use this hostname as `xdebug.client_host`. Usually, `host.docker.internal` works okay.

Also, make sure to disable `Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations` until you actually get a debug session in PhpStorm - it's 100% that the *PHP | Servers* entry that you have created manually is wrong, and thus all incoming sessions will be ignored